# Quick Local Min/Max Question

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, definite-integrals

I was given the following question:

"Consider the curve defined by $y^2-x^2y=6$ for $y>0$"

"Show that there is a point $P$ with $x$-coordinate $0$ at which the line tangent to the curve at $P$ is horizontal. Find the $y$-coordinate of $P$."

"Find the value of $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ at the point $P$"

Although this question is fairly easy, I was only taught how to tackle something like this with just one variable (which is done by setting the derivative equal to $0$ and solving) but I'm lost here, I'm not too sure how to tackle something like this with two variables. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

As $$y^2-x^2y-6=0$$
and
$$y>0,$$

we conclude that
$$y=\frac{x^2+\sqrt{x^4+24}}{2}$$
$$=f(x)=g(x^2)$$
with

$$g(x)=\frac{x+\sqrt{24+x^2}}{2}$$

$$f'(x)=2xg'(x^2)$$

thus $$f'(0)=0$$

and
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=2\Bigl(g'(x^2)+2x^2g''(x^2)\Bigr)$$

At the point P $(x=0) $, we find

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=2g'(0)=1$$